# Appropriate level representation / data structure for a 2D platform game?

Tags: java, data-structures, 2d

I'm about to program a copy of Mario in Java. I'm thinking on 2 representations/data structures for the levels but I'm not sure which one should I choose:

- A 2D integer array.
- A quadtree to divide the level in pieces.

What are its advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking how to divide the map? The game?

Comment: The map. Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: cross-post http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16306/6588

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely a 2d array of some type. Integers would be a good idea, however characters would be an even better idea.

Consider making a text file which is basically a "map". It could be 10 rows by 10 columns of text. A very simple map, in this case. Maybe you could use an "a" to signify grass, and a "b" to signify brick. In this way, you could even visually understand your map before you put it into action. But you could basically program your application to depend on this text file for the map.

For instance, consider this map:

```
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

So, that would look like a long brick road above 3 long rows of grass. Imagine making this scheme much more complicated, using all kinds of characters a-z and A-Z, even punctuation like $ or % or &.

Then, you could create maps on the fly just by altering the text file. If you use integers, you are limited to only 10 characters (or 10 map objects, per se). For instance, what if you have more 10 objects, then how could you make a text file where the digits are next to each other. You won't know how to seperate the digits.

The downside of a quadtree is that it's overly complicated and won't allow for quick access to specific elements.

Comment: ` If you use integers, you are limited to only 10 characters (or 10 map objects, per se).` -- This confuses me as an int can be quite large, up to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: because if you want a visual map in a text file as I was saying, you could easily confuse 1 digit integers and more than one digit integers.

Comment: +1 I've gone this route before - makes notepad your level editor

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) If I use a text file for the map, how can I manage to get or set values in ejecution from it?
For example, if I use a 2D array and my tile's width is always 36 pixels and I need to get the corresponding cell of a sprite I can get it by doing: sprite.x/36 or something like that, but I have no idea of how can I do it with a text file.

Comment: You will first need to read the text file into a 2D array at the beginning of your program. Then, you'll be able to do what you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

Really, it's up to you. One way I can think of doing it is to have an 2d array of map tiles, either clear or an object. Tiles would have a certain size. Of course, then you have the problem of if somethings half a tile. Another option is an array of objects with the object data and location inside. This is less efficient, unless you sort the data.

If you think your maps are going to be very heavy on objects, I'd suggest a 2d tile map. Otherwise, I'd go with an array of objects or parallel arrays (your choice) specifying location and type of an item.

Comment: Thank you for you answer :) By the way, how can I solve the "something is half a tile" problem?

Comment: Make your tiles smaller? I'm not sure exactly. Perhaps you could store an "offset" value.

Comment: @Rama The offset from the center. ex: 5 units x and -3 y from the center